# Number of Rows and Columns in Julia DataFrames

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a Julia `DataFrame`:

```
df = DataFrame(a=1:4,b=5:8, c=["a", "b", "c", "d"])

4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      c      
     │ Int64  Int64  String 
─────┼──────────────────────
   1 │     1      5  a
   2 │     2      6  b
   3 │     3      7  c
   4 │     4      8  d
```

How do I get the number of rows an columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soultion 1

```
nrow(df)
4

ncol(df)
3
```

Solution 2

```
size(df,1)
4

size(df,2)
3
```

Comment: Is there any worth mentioning difference between the two methods?

Comment: These are completely equivalent, except that `nrow` can be used e.g. in `combine(groupby(df, :x), nrow)` to compute the number of rows per group more efficiently and conveniently than `size(df, 1)`.